# Is there a more efficient way to loop through pages?

Tags: templates

I have a site that uses a set of 3 images for the header of its subpages. Each page has a different set of images. From what I could find, my best way to accomplish this would be to place an if statement within my `header-subpage.php`. The following is a snippet of my code.

```
<?php
if ( is_page( 'available-homes' ) ) {
    get_template_part( 'sections/banner-images', 'available-homes' );
} elseif ( is_page( 'design-services' ) ) {
    get_template_part( 'sections/banner-images', 'design-services' );
} elseif ( is_page( 'about-us' ) ) {
    get_template_part( 'sections/banner-images', 'about-us' );
} ........

} elseif ( is_page( 'portfolio' ) ) {                          
    get_template_part( 'sections/banner-images', 'portfolio' );
} elseif ( is_page( 'galleries' ) ) {
    get_template_part( 'sections/banner-images', 'galleries' );
} else {
    echo "page images undefined...";
}
```

Is there a more efficient way for me to do this? I am still learning PHP, but it seems like there might be a better more efficient way to loop through the pages than what I have done.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to `if... else...` you can use the control structure [`switch`](http://Switch%20Case%20acts%20similar%20to%20Elseif%20control%20structure.%20Main%20difference%20is%20that%20Switch%20Case%20can%20be%20written%20in%20a%20way%20that%20it%20compares%20a%20given%20value%20with%20a%20set%20of%20predefined%20values%20without%20evaluating%20set%20of%20conditions.) functionality. But if you use `if... elseif...` or `switch` is mainly a matter of preference. The performance is the same.

### if else

```
if ($i == 0) {
    echo "i equals 0";
} elseif ($i == 1) {
    echo "i equals 1";
} elseif ($i == 2) {
    echo "i equals 2";
}
```

### switch

```
switch ($i) {
    case 0:
        echo "i equals 0";
        break;
    case 1:
        echo "i equals 1";
        break;
    case 2:
        echo "i equals 2";
        break;
}
```

Switch Case acts similar to Elseif control structure. The main difference is that Switch Case can be written in a way that it compares a given value with a set of predefined values without evaluating a set of conditions.

### Opinion

In my opinion, `switch is more readable and this is also important for maintenance. If you need this check for a template more often you should think about a function, so that you don't write recurring code.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! Like you said, the switch alternative is much more readable, so I will go with that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that the second part of your template names are the same as the page slugs. If that's the case then just use the page slug as the second argument of `get_template_part()` and you won't need any loops, conditions or switches at all:

```
<?php
$slug = get_queried_object()->post_name;

get_template_part( 'sections/banner-images', $slug );
```

And if the template for that slug doesn't exist it will just fall back to `sections/banner-images.php`.

We also note that `is_page()` can check for array of slugs.

Comment: Very interesting. Thank you for suggestion. With the suggestions provided here and below I think I just solved 4 other problems too!